# Easy platform for a small metal frame pool

Tags: pool, level, backyard

Recently I have been thinking about purchasing a small metal frame pool, something simple that can be taken down during the fall/winter seasons.  The issue I have is my entire backyard is on a slight but noticeable slope.

Is it possible to just use sand bags and wood sheeting to build a temporary and removable platform to put the pool on ?

Part of our backyard is asphalted and attached to our drive way and leads to a garage.  I figured since we never park our car in the driveway any way we can use that asphalted area to stack some sandbags and lay wood sheeting over top so more level.

I'm really looking for a simple removable platform that we can use and then take down when we put the pool away.

Comment: With the amount of weight that even a small pool will have, "Simple" may not be safe. You need to know the weight of the pool empty, the weight of the total water capacity ( 8 pounds per gallon ) and the weight of the maximum occupancy of humans. **Add those up and then you know how much total weight your platform needs to SAFELY support**.

Comment: That's good to know.  From my estimate i would need a layer of sand bags that is at least 2 sandbags high on the low end and one sandbag high on the short end (the slope isn't too noticeable but you can tell its there.  Our plan for the future is to have a concrete patio that is level and has space for a pool like this.  We were just hoping for something we could use in the mean time.

Comment: You do not mention beams to support the plywood ?  You need beams,  many and strong. 500 gallons of water weights 4000 pounds. The average bath tub holds about 62 gallons.

Comment: I wasn't planning on using beams in the platform to level off the area I just need to get a platform that raises one side at most 2.5 inches up.  I know could probably not put that much water in the pool but from what I read about these things the liners are flimsy and and if one side is holding more weight than the others its not going to last that long.

Comment: Sandbags are thicker than 2 1/2 inches. I would just put it on the asphalt and deal with it being slightly slanted, just don’t fill it quite as full. It’s only temporary right?

Comment: Yes the long term plan is to have a level concrete patio in the area.

Comment: I have seen a pool collapse it took my fence out but was my neighbors. He did not see that I had leveled with sand when his son jumped in the first time the low side gave out, his son only got a bunch of splinters from the fence , it could have been worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sand bags would be a good idea. I normally use railroad ties drive a piece of rebar through the tie into the ground and fill the area with beach sand (I live close to the ocean and sand is free). I would put a tarp down over the asphalt and the filled in area so it won’t wash out , I haven’t used plywood just a tarp it helped to extend the life of the liner. Some 25 years ago I used to take temp pools down but now I don’t a week and a half of vacuuming leaves out and the kids are in it in May even in Oregon they are nuts!

Comment: Hi Ed.  Would you mind taking a minute or two to tidy up your answer?  "25 years ago I used to take them down"—what is *them*?  "now I don't a week and a half"—please clarify.  "kids are in it even in Oregon already they are nuts!"?  Looks like two or more sentences are in there.